# Get file through API call (R & plumber)

Tags: r, file, asp.net-web-api, plumber

I'm using plumber as a simple web-api service for some R functions.

I would like to provide a file 'download' (on the client side) through an R function very much like [flask is doing it in python through send_file and send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file).

I tried

```
#* @get /datafile
get_file <- function(){
  return(file('path-to-file.RData'))
}
```

But unfortunately it didn't work (because the return value cannot be transformed to JSON). I'm aware of [static file server option in plubmer](https://plumber.trestletech.com/docs/static/), but I really want to provide only one single file and not a directory. (Although serving files in directory through `@assets` seems to be a more secure option.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry this isn't better documented, but see some examples here: https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/blob/master/tests/testthat/files/includes.R

I don't remember if I've tested with binary data or how it will handle the Rdata content type, so if things are still weird [please open a ticket](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues).

Comment: yes, thanks, `include_file` works for text type and unfortunately you are right - it does not work with RData.